# Calculus word problem( multivariable)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

A manufacturer sells three types of fertilizers, which are mixtures of three products A, B and C.

The fertilizer of the type I contains, by unit:
 $10$ kg of A, $30$ kg of B and $60$ kg of C

that of type II:
 $20$ kg of A, $30$ kg of B and $50$ kg of C

that of type III:
 $50$ kg of A and $50$ kg of C.

There are currently in stock $2000$ kg of A, $900$ kg of B and $3100$ kg of C. How many units of each type of fertilizer does the manufacturer have to produce if they want to dispose of all the raw materials in stock?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Just name $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ the quantities of product $I$, $II$ and $III$ which will be made. Now, what do they contain ?

Concerning $A$, you have $$10 x_1+20 x_2 +50 x_3=2000$$  Do just the same for $B$ and $C$. So you have three equations for three unknowns and you have to solve it.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

It is a system of linear equation  with

$n_1$ = No of units of Fertilizer Type I

$n_2$ = No of units of Fertilizer Type II

$n_3$ = No of units of Fertilizer Type III

Linear system of equations:

$$10n_1+20n_2+50n_3 = 2000$$
$$30n_1+30n_2 = 900$$
$$60n_1+50n_2+50n_3 = 3100$$

Solve it using Matrix Algebra:

The solution is $n_1$ = 10, $n_2$=20, $n_3$ = 30

We are living in a sophisticated world, $$Matrix(N) = MatrixA^{-1} MatrixB$$

Just to help you further to start using Excel

Here is a set up, Good Luck[image]